# How to hide User control from another user control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I am working in an school project in C# but I have a problem. I made a user control in which i have some buttons, this is like a banner with buttons in it. Those buttons should SHOW and HIDE other User Controls

Here is my code in the User Control that has the button:

```
 Reports ra = new Reports();
 PurchaseReport rb = new PurchaseReport();
```

than in one of the button i wrote this code:

```
 ra.Hide();

 rb.Show();
 this.Controls.Add(rb);
 rb.Location = new Point(130, 153);
```

But the problem is that it doesn't hide the Reports (ra). And it doesn't show the Purchase Report (rb). What is the problem?

```
public partial class MenuUserC : UserControl
{

    Reports ra = new Reports();
    PurchaseReport rb = new PurchaseReport();

    public MenuUserC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonItem15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rb.Hide();

        ra.Show();
        this.Controls.Add(ra);
        ra.Location = new Point(130, 153);
    }

    private void ButtonItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ra.Hide();

        rb.Show();
        this.Controls.Add(rb);
        rb.Location = new Point(130, 153);

    }
```

Comment: Sounds like your button code isn't getting called.  Are you sure the button code is getting executed??

Comment: what type of application are you building?   web?  winforms?  MVC? WPF?

Comment: I believe you can use the Visibility dependency property to hide and show usercontrols (WPF)?

Comment: This banner is a custom user control that you're placing on the main form?

Comment: I use C#. I edited my post there and wrote all my code that is in the USER CONTROL that has all the buttons. Please help me guys :(

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you do NOT want one Control to know about the other.
Make your custom Controls expose events when something interesting happens and let the application code handle the logic to show/hide other controls.

For example:

```
MyUserControl ctl = new MyUserControl;
ctl.OnHideReports += OnHideReports;
ctl.OnShowReports += OnShowReports;
...
```

Then in the event handler for OnHideReports, handle the logic:

```
void OnHideReports(...)
{
    _reports.Hide();
    _purchaseReports.Show();
    ...
}
```

Also, try to add your user controls to the Form using the WinForm designer. It is much easier to work with Controls from the designer versus declaring them directly in the code.

Update:

This example has two buttons on a form plus two user Controls. When Button 1 is clicked, it shows User Control 1 and hides User Control 2. When Button 2 is clicked, it does the reverse. Note that the buttons and user Controls are added to the form using the Forms designer, not manually in code. This will take care of positioning, adding them as child controls to the main form etc. Do not manually add them with your own code unless you have a good reason to do so.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UiButtonOneClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myUserControlOne.Show();
        myUserControlTwo.Hide();
    }

    private void UiButtonTwoClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myUserControlOne.Hide();
        myUserControlTwo.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my post above. There I wrote all my code that i use in the User Control that has the buttons. Because I can't follow you  :( :( Sorry I am a newbi in C#.Programming

Comment: Aha, well, it seems you want to create a control that has one/two buttons that basically toggles another part of the control from reports to purchase reports, and vice versa. A user Control should be a well defined entity with a single responsibility. Maybe what you are looking for is instead a Form containing those buttons and a separate part of the form that shows either a standard report or a purchase report? If so, you do not need a big compound user Control. Create a form with those buttons and one normal report sub-control and a purchase sub-control and show/hide those on button clicks.

Comment: Mollas - Yes, maybe I can create another form but the problem is that it fits nowhere.... The application is an Market Application. And this part is the Reports (Sales Reports, Purchase Reports etc). An it is in the end of my Menu Buttons. If I create an form that will play the role of this USER COntrol. How can I make that form UNMOVABLE ? Because what if the user tries to move it?

Comment: Hm, I do not really understand what you are trying to achieve here. I Think you need to add more explanation to the original question in order to get a good answer.

Comment: Sorry if I can't explain good. I will try again.

You saw the code up there?! The code is written in an User Control that has 4 buttons and it is placed on the left side. These buttons have to Open 4 new USER CONTROLS. For Example: If I click on the First Button should open the FIrst User Control and HIDE UserControl2, UserControl3, UserControl4. If I click on the Second button it should show the UserControl2 and HIDE UserControl1, UserControl3 adn UserContrl4 etc etc. I hope you understand me now?

Comment: Updated the answer. Not sure how much help it is. You may want to resort to a good book on C#/.NET WinForm coding, see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357545/book-recommendation-for-winforms-design-programming) for tips on that.

Answer (score 3):

Try hide method as well as the show method for the other object

Answer (score 1):

you are creating a new instance of the user controls

instead you need something like this

```
Reports ra = (Reports)Page.FindControl("Reports1");//Reports1 should be the name the controls renders in the browser
```

that will give you access to the instance on the page
my syntax might be off a little, last time i did this was in VB

Comment: I edited my post above. There I wrote all my code that i use in the User Control that has the buttons